# Values of char* parameter changing inside function

Tags: c, pointers, memory, heap-memory

I want to create a program that creates a 2D array and populates it from stdin for later manipulation. Initially, I designed it so that function *takeInput()* takes the user's input and returns a char* of a single string with all the one-digit integers. Then, my intent was to get this char* and pass it on as a parameter into a second function *createArray()* that would populate the array accordingly.

The issue occurs when the values of my parameter char* begin changing (losing values) inside the second function.

**Note:** I've allocated memory for the char* using malloc inside the first function with the intention that this will not make its values local to the function.

My main looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "functions.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    const char *string = takeInput();
    int **initState = createArray(3, 3, string);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the first function:

```
const char* takeInput() {
    char string2[10];
    /* some code */
    char *string0 = malloc(sizeof(string2));
    string0 = string2;
    return string0;
}
```

This is the second function:

```
int **createArray(int rows, int columns, const char *string) {
    int **array;
    int traverse = 0;
    // allocating memory for number of rows
    array = malloc(rows * sizeof(int*));

    // allocating memory for number of columns
    for(int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++) {
        array[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof(int));
    }

    // populating indices in 2D array with values from string
    for(int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++) {

        for(int j = 0 ; j < columns ; j++) {

            // converting chars to digits or the '_' char 
            if (string[traverse] != 95) {
                array[i][j] = (string[traverse] - 48);
            }

            else {
                array[i][j] = 48;
            }
            traverse++;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

The values of `const char *string` being changing as soon as my code reaches the first for-loop and decrease in size through the rest of the code. Any ideas/suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: The line `string0 = string2;` does not copy the values into the allocated memory, it just changes what `string0` points to, and [leaks the allocated memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). You should remove `string2`, and `/* some code */` should write the values directly into the allocated memory.

Comment: @user3386109, thanks a lot! Using strcpy() solves this issue rather than using '=' to copy the address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program has undefined behavior because in this function

```
const char* takeInput() {
    char string2[10];
    /* some code */
    char *string0 = malloc(sizeof(string2));
    string0 = string2;
    return string0;
}
```

a pointer to a local array

```
    string0 = string2;
    return string0;
```

is returned. And moreover the function has a memory leak because a memory allocated and its address is assigned to the pointer string0 and then the pointer is reassigned.

If the array string2 contains a string then you can use the standard C function `strcpy` like

```
strcpy( string0, string2 );
```

Otherwise use the function `memcpy`.

Pay attention to that it is a bad idea to use magic numbers like 95 or 48 in this code snippet

```
        // converting chars to digits or the '_' char 
        if (string[traverse] != 95) {
            array[i][j] = (string[traverse] - 48);
        }

        else {
            array[i][j] = 48;
        }
```

It seems you mean the following

```
        // converting chars to digits or the '_' char 
        if (string[traverse] != '_' ) {
            array[i][j] = (string[traverse] - '0');
        }

        else {
            array[i][j] = '0';
        }
```

though maybe in the else statement you mean 0 instead of '0'

```
        else {
            array[i][j] = 0;
        }
```

Comment: This makes so much sense! I was breaking my head over the fact that I wasn't sure why the memory leak was occurring, but the fact that I passed the address of string2 instead of its content answer my question entirely. Regarding the 95 and 48, my intent was to convert the chars to ints or the ASCII char 95 '_' but I can see how that can become an issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You return the address of a local variable, which's life time will end once the function returns. Accessing this address afterwards yields undefined behaviour.

```
const char* takeInput() {
    char string2[10];
    char *string0 = malloc(sizeof(string2));
    string0 = string2;  // NOTE: string2 is not copied; string0 will just point to the address of string2 then
    return string0;     // here you actually return the address of string2
}
```

use `strcpy` instead:

```
const char* takeInput() {
    char string2[10] = { 0 };
    // some code...
    char *string0 = malloc(sizeof(string2));
    strcpy(string0,string2);
    return string0;
}
```